# Laravel : QueryBuilder with max(date)

Tags: laravel, max

I want to retrieve all the rows in the database which have a criteres_id to 30. Except that it is a log table, so I have several occurrences with the same products_id. I would like to recover the products_id which has the highest date.

my table :

```
products_id = 1  date = 10/12/2020
products_id = 2  date = 10/12/2020
products_id = 2  date = 4/10/2020
products_id = 3  date = 9/12/2020
products_id = 3  date = 1/12/2020
```

I want to take

```
products_id = 1  date = 10/12/2020
products_id = 2  date = 10/12/2020
products_id = 3  date = 9/12/2020
```

my request sql :

```
SELECT MAX( DATE ) , products_id, criteres_value
FROM `products_main_criteres_history`
WHERE `manufacturers_id`
IN ( 263962, 263961 )
AND `criteres_id` =30
GROUP BY products_id
```

I try to make that :

```
ProductMainCritereHistory::
    select('products_id')
    ->max('date')
    ->where('criteres_id', '=', '30')
    ->where('manufacturers_id', '<', '1000')
    ->groupBy('products_id')
    ->get();
```

thks for your help

Comment: You should be able to order your rows by date in desc order like so: `->orderBy('date', 'desc')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the given solution query. In this case, you can use `groupBy` to get the unique record only along with sort by date ascending so you'll get the desired result.

```php
$data = ProductMainCritereHistory::where('criteres_id', '=', '30')
            ->where('manufacturers_id', '<', '1000')
            ->orderBy('date','asc')
            ->groupBy('products_id')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

here's my solution :

```
ProductMainCritereHistory::
    select('products_id')
    ->orderBy('date', 'desc')
    ->where('criteres_id', '=', '30')
    ->where('criteres_value', '>', '1')
    ->where('manufacturers_id', '<', '1000')
    ->groupBy('products_id')
    ->get();
```